# done() called within superagent request not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, superagent

I am creating an app with a feature to post on login. I have written the following test code in mocha. I get this error:

`Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

I think I made some mistake in using done(). All other assert statements have passed. Let me know where I am going wrong, or if if you need more info.

```
it("Login and post", function(done) {
    superagent
        .post(URL_ROOT + "/register")
        .send({
            email: "posttest@test.com",
            password: "posttest"
        })
        .end(function(err, res) {
            assert.ifError(err);
            var token = res.body.token;
            superagent
                .post(URL_ROOT + "/post")
                .send({
                    content: "testing post",
                    user: jwt.decode(token).id
                })
                .set("Authorization", "test_scheme " + token)
                .end(function(err, res){
                    assert.ifError(err);
                    assert.equal(res.body.post.content, "testing post");
                    done();
                });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test might be taking more than 2 seconds to run: In the first line of your callback to `it`, right before `superagent
        .post(URL_ROOT + "/register")...` add this line:

`this.timeout(30000)`

This allows your to only time out after 30 seconds instead of 2.